# unnest json column with `dbplyr` and `RPostgres`

Tags: r, json, postgresql, dbplyr

I have a column containing *json* strings in a table on a *PostgreSQL* DB.

I want to unnest it on the server side, and I was able to figure out the SQL code to do that. The challenge I'm facing is that I would like to be able to insert this operation in a `dbplyr` pipe chain, i.e. update the `tbl_lazy` object and not run the query yet, and I don't understand the internals of *dbplyr* enough to do that.

See example below  :

**Setup**

```
library("RPostgres")
library("dplyr")

drv <- RPostgres::dbDriver("Postgres")
#### NOT REPRODUCIBLE!!! ####
con <- RPostgres::dbConnect(drv, dbname = mydbname, sslmode = 'require',
                            host = myhost, port = 5432,
                            user = user, password = mypassword)
#############################

my_tbl <- tribble(~a, ~bcd,
        1, '{"b": "foo1", "c": "bar1", "d": "baz1"}',
        2, '{"b": "foo2", "c": "bar2", "d": "baz2"}')

copy_to(con, my_tbl, "my_tbl",
        temporary = TRUE)
```

**Partial solution (no lazy evaluation)**

```
unnest_json <-function(data, json_col, ...){
  # build character vector whose names are cols to be created and values columns
  # to be extracted 
  dots <- sapply(as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1], as.character)
  json_col <- as.character(substitute(json_col))
  # json extraction string
  query0  <- sprintf("%s::json->'%s' as %s",json_col, dots, names(dots))
  # complete query
  query <- sprintf("SELECT *, %s FROM (%s) AS PREV", 
                   paste(query0, collapse = ", "), 
                   dbplyr::sql_render(data))
  # fetch (when I'd rather update the tbl_lazy object instead)
  dbGetQuery(data$src$con, query)
}

con %>%
  tbl("my_tbl") %>%
  unnest_json(bcd, unnested_b = "b", unnested_c = "c")
#   a                                     bcd unnested_b unnested_c
# 1 1 {"b": "foo1", "c": "bar1", "d": "baz1"}     "foo1"     "bar1"
# 2 2 {"b": "foo2", "c": "bar2", "d": "baz2"}     "foo2"     "bar2"
```

**Desired feature**

I would like to be able to do, for instance :

```
con %>%
  tbl("my_tbl") %>%
  unnest_json(bcd, unnested_b = "b", unnested_c = "c") %>% # not evaluated at this point 
  select(-bcd) %>%
  head(1) %>%
  collect() 

#   a unnested_b unnested_c
# 1 1     "foo1"     "bar1"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to use the function `sql` into a call to `tbl`.

`sql` should be fed the string containing the query.

So the function becomes :

```
unnest_json <-function(.data,.json_col, ...){
  # build character vector whose names are cols to be created and values columns
  # to be extracted 
  dots <- sapply(as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1], as.character)
  .json_col <- as.character(substitute(.json_col))
  query0  <- sprintf("%s::json ->>'%s' as %s", .json_col, dots, names(dots))
  query <- sprintf("SELECT *, %s FROM (%s) AS PREV", 
                   paste(query0, collapse = ", "), 
                   dbplyr::sql_render(.data))
  tbl(.data$src$con, sql(query))
}
```

I also changed `->` to `->>` in the query to get the right output.

ouput of `unnest_json` :

```
con %>%
  tbl("my_tbl") %>%
  unnest_json(bcd, unnested_b = "b", unnested_c = "c")
# # Source:   SQL [?? x 4]
# # Database: postgres [standtasic@adbsg@adbsg.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/standtasicdb]
#       a bcd                                                   unnested_b unnested_c
#   <dbl> <chr>                                                 <chr>      <chr>     
# 1     1 "{\"b\": \"foo1\", \"c\": \"bar1\", \"d\": \"baz1\"}" foo1       bar1      
# 2     2 "{\"b\": \"foo1\", \"c\": \"bar1\", \"d\": \"baz1\"}" foo1       bar1
```

used in a `dbplyr` chain and collected :

```
con %>%
  tbl("my_tbl") %>%
  unnest_json(bcd, unnested_b = "b", unnested_c = "c") %>%
  select(-bcd) %>%
  head(1) %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#         a unnested_b unnested_c
#     <dbl> <chr>      <chr>
#   1     1 foo1       bar1
```

Comment: How would you extend this to unnest a list? i.e., make `test_list <- list(unnested_b = "b", unnested_c = "c")` and then run 
```con %>%
  tbl("my_tbl") %>%
  unnest_json(test_list)```

Comment: I don't have the setup to reproduce this right now but I think the way I treat dots is unnecessary complicated, I think I only need `dots <- c(...)`in the first line of the function. To handle lists as well you would just have to do `dots <- unlist(c(...))` instead. Again I cannot test this atm but if that works I'm happy to update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @moodymudskipper!
I wanted to see how to extend this answer by supplying a list. Here's how I did it:

1. Update the function by removing intermediate step that creates `dots` list

```
unnest_json <-function(.data,.json_col, ...){
  .json_col <- as.character(substitute(.json_col))
  query0  <- sprintf("%s::json ->>'%s' as %s", .json_col, ..., names(...))
  query <- sprintf("SELECT assessment_id, %s FROM (%s) AS PREV", 
                   paste(query0, collapse = ", "), 
                   dbplyr::sql_render(.data))
  tbl(.data$src$con, sql(query))
}
```

2. Create new function that builds dots list

```
make_list <- function(...) {
  dots <- rlang::list2(...)
  set_names(dots, dots) # note for my purposes, I wanted the columns to be named the same
}
```

3. Build the list (which can be pulled here from a tibble

```
my_df <- tibble(my_list = c("b","c"))
test_list <- make_list(!!! as.list(my_df$my_list))
test_list2 <- sapply(test_list, as.character)
```

4. Run code

```
con |>
  tbl("my_tbl") |>
  unnest_json(test_list2)
```

`list2` reference: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/list2.html

Comment: I believe `test_list2` can be built more easily with `set_names(my_df$my_list)`

Comment: In your solution the dots are not used at all (and if they would I believe it would crash) and you don't provide the column to extract from, are you sure this is working for you ?

Comment: Yes, definitely works for me.